# Self-signed SSL certificates vs CA-signed certificates

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

While reading about certificates, I came across [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-when-are-self-signed-certificates-acceptable.html) article. It says:

> The point of a CA-signed certificate is to give slightly stronger verification that you are actually using the key that belongs to the server you are trying to connect to.

How exactly does the CA ensure *stronger* verification?

While trying to find an answer to this, I found [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82909/223744). The fifth paragraph mentions:

> Once you get the certificate, you want to verify it's the good one. You can see in the certificate that it has been issue by a CA. If you have the CA key you can verify the signature.

What does this mean? Everyone who's trying to access any site with a CA-signed certificate will have this universal CA key? If yes, isn't that insecure in any way? If no, then how do you verify that it isn't a "forged" certificate from the CA?

(I'd appreciate an in-depth explanation of how CA-signed certificates actually work.)

Comment: *"I'd appreciate an in-depth explanation of how CA-signed certificates actually work"* - there are several similar question with good answers on this site. Please study these first. If you still have question please focus on the parts not already answered or which you don't understand from the existing answers.